# Interpolate line between 2 lines in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4

[image]

I have 2 lines, A and B as picture. Line A has value Z 60.79m and line B has value Z 58.75m. I want to interpolate line C which is between line A-B and has the value Z between the value Z of line A and B (60.79 to 58.75). To make it simple, I choose the value Z of line C is 60m.

How can I solve this in ArcGIS 10.4.1?

Comment: Do you have a DEM, TIN or Terrain that the isolines are derived from? Do you have 3d and/or spatial analyst extension? You could create a TIN or Terrain if you don't have one already and use Contour List (3d or SA) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000tt000000 and enter 60 into the list of contour values to create a contour at 60m only.

Comment: If you create a polygon from the lines you can try Polygon to Centerline Tool: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=bc642731870740aabf48134f90aa6165

Comment: @SonofaBeach I want to create a line C feature, but it must be interpolated between line A and B with the Z-value between the Z-value of A and B.

Comment: @MichaelStimson thank you. I created a TIN but there is some space in TIN is not full fill with the color ramp, do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you want to interpolate line C on its Z-value, Use Feature To 3D By Attribute Tool to interpolate line C on its Z-value stored in a field.

In Addition, if you want to insert Z-value in line C based on line A and B, you can create A TIN using Line A and B Z-values, through Create TIN Tool, and use Interpolate Shape Tool to interpolate line C on the basis of created TIN Surface.